# Rank of a 0-1-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$. Let $M \in K^{n \times m}$ be a matrix such that every entry of $M$ is either $0$ or $1$. About this matrix, I know further that each sum over a column and a row is a constant number, i.e.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n M_{ij} = c_{\text{column}} \forall j=1,...,m$$

and

$$\sum_{j=1}^m M_{ij} = c_{\text{row}} \forall i=1,...,n$$

for some $c_{\text{column}}, c_{\text{row}}$ both lying in $\{1,2,3,...\}$.

Question: Can one say something about the rank of $M$ in this situation? If not, does somebody know a criterion that leads to some inequality like ''if condition is satisfied then

$$\text{rank}(M) \geq f(n,m,c_{\text{column}}, c_{\text{row}})$$

for some function $f$''?

Comment: does your $\mathbb{N}$ include 0?

Comment: sorry, no, of course not!

Comment: good to know (there are varying opinions on this)

Comment: Also posted to MO, without any indication at either site.

Answer (score 3):

There is a paper dealing with that by Odlyzko (ON THE RANKS OF SOME (0, 1)-MATRICES WITH CONSTANT ROW SUMS, Austral. Math. Soc. (Series A) 31 (1981), 193-201) stating the following: Take a matrix $M \in \{0,1\}^{a \times n}$ viewed as a matrix in $K^{a \times n}$ for any field $K$ of characteristic $0$. Assume further that the row-sum is constantly $m$, then: If rank($M$) $\leq n-1$, then there may be no more than

$$g(n,m) := \begin{cases} 
              {n-1}\choose m & \text{if $1 \leq m < n/2$} \\
              2 \cdot {{n-2}\choose {(n-2)/2}} & \text{if $m = n/2$} \\
              {n-1}\choose {m-1} & \text{if $n/2 < m \leq n$} \\
            \end{cases}$$

Reformulated, this means that if one knows that there are strictly more than $g(n,m)$ **distinct** $\{0,1\}$-vectors among those $a$ rows of $M$, then $M$ has full rank.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could tell a lot from this. Consider for example the matrices
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1&0&0\\0 &1&1&0 \\0&0&1&1\\1&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1&0&0\\1 &1&0&0 \\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1 \end{bmatrix}$$
both have all of the same parameters for $n,m,c_r,c_c$ but they have different ranks

Comment: Yes, ok, but can one say something about the rank... i.e. ANYthing, not necessarily rank($M$)=... but rank($M$) $\geq$ ... if some condition is satisfied or so?

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure if you'd have a nice formula for it. However for example, with $m=n=4 , c_r=c_n=2$ we can't have all rows the same so the rank is at least two. You could possibly use combinatorics to figure out some relationships but I'm not sure you'll get anything particularly strong out of it.