# Rank of a (0,1) matrix.

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A=\left[a_{ij}\right]$ be an $m \times n$, $m\geq n$ zero-one matrix. Is there any relation between $rank(A)$ and sum of its columns?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take the square identity matrix and the one with first row $(1,1,\ldots,1)$, all other rows zero. Then the ranks are quite different, but the column sum is the same.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409933/rank-of-a-0-1-matrix) is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the rank is clearly bounded by the number of positive terms in the sum of all the columns.

If the number of distinct terms in the sum of all columns is $c$ then we can also guarantee $\text {rank} (M)\geq c-\delta$. Where $\delta$ is $1$ if the sum contains a $0$ term and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Is there any way to calculate the exact rank of a (0,1) matrix by columns sum?

Comment: no of course not.

Comment: for example consider the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end {pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

The term rank provides a convenient generalization of the SDR concept for the subsets $S_1, \cdots, S_m$ of an $n$-set $S$. For if A is the incidence matrix for these subsets, then the subsets have an SDR if and only if the term rank of A equals m. It´s define only if $m\leq n$, $A_{m\times n}$.